# required url param on React router v5 with typescript, can be undefined

Tags: typescript, types, react-router

I am using react-router v5.1 with TypeScript and have this route configurations:

```js
<Router basename="/" hashType="slash">
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/token/:tokenName">
            <TokenPage />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

and I try to access the url param (tokenName) in the component, with useParams hook like so:

```js
const TokenPage: FC<TokenPageProps> = props => {
    const { tokenName } = useParams()
    ...
}
```

However, typescript thinks that `tokenName` param can be undefined:

[image: wrong tokenName typing]

which does not make sense since react router won't match this route if the param is missing in the URL.

How can I fix the typing in that situation?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In this situation, your `TokenPage` code is unaware it is being wrapped by a `Route`. You are right that if the URL does not contain the proper parameters, your component wouldn't be rendered. But Typescript isn't aware of this.

The default typing you got there is proper and you should null check the value before using it.

If ever you would want to override the typing, `useParams` is generic and accepts a type specifying the return value type.

```js
interface ParamTypes {
  tokenName: string
}
const { tokenName } = useParams<ParamTypes>()
```

---

**EDIT 09/29/20**

The [latest typing](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cbbbfecf4533864c7f1f939618dcef67f8a8b5df/types/react-router/index.d.ts) for `useParams` changed.

```js
export function useParams<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}>(): Params;
```

As you can see, the new default is `{}` which will not imply any of the keys contained, but the generic constraints does assume that the values are of type `string`.

So the following line would now yield a `Property 'tokenName' does not exist on type '{}'.` TypeScript error.

```js
const { tokenName } = useParams()
```

To fix this, either you type the `useParams` with known parameters like in the first example, or you type it like this:

```js
const { tokenName } = useParams<Record<string, string | undefined>>()
```

Comment: Base on the last update you would need to add the following interface as an alternative to type assertion:

`interface ParamTypes {
  tokenName?: string;
}`

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette The generic typing of `useParams` have no impact on whether or not you should expect fields to be nullable or not. You could go with either. If you know for sure it will be defined, which is basically what the question is asking for here, you can keep it without the `?` and avoid null checking this everywhere.

Answer (score 21):

Using the original idea of overriding the type, you don't need to create a new named interface, it can be done directly in the type parameter:

```
const { tokenName } = useParams<{ tokenName: string }>();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in v6, tokenName will still be string | undefined.

Comment: Pity. Presumably this affects the accepted answer, because this is just a shorthand for the other version.

Comment: That's right, yeah. The only way I could find to do this was `useParams() as { myparam: string };`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how to manage it with enum

```
export const enum ROUTE_PATH {
  DASHBOARD = 'dashboard'
}
export const enum ROUTE_PARAM {
  DASH_ID = 'DASH_ID',
}
<Route path={`${ROUTE_PATH.DASHBOARD}/:${ROUTE_PARAM.DASH_ID}`} />
const { DASH_ID } = useParams<ROUTE_PARAM>();
```