# Getting Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'RouteComponentProps error when migrating to react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

We are having legacy class based code for which we are trying to migrate to latest react router that is version 6. During migration we are getting this error:

> Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'RouteComponentProps'

We have added `withRouter` wrapper to add the legacy support.

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return <Component {...props} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />;
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter;
```

Our class based component looks like this:

```
import { Route, RouteComponentProps, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component<{} & RouteComponentProps<{}>, IState> {
  constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       prop1: null
    };
  }
   
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.location.pathname === "/test") {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  };

   
  render() {
     return (
          <Routes>
               <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
          </Routes>
     )
  }
 }
 
export default withRouter(App);
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70378978/react-typescript-module-react-router-dom-has-no-exported-member-routecompo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

- `react-router-dom@6` doesn't export any `RouteComponentProps` type. In fact, RRD6 completely did away with route props, the former `location`, `navigate`, and `params` values are now accessed using `useLocation`, `useNavigate`, and `useParams` respectively.
- The `withRouter` Higher Order Component isn't injecting "route params", it is injecting a single prop named `router` that has the "route params".

## Solution

In most cases the answer to "How do I fix this issue?" is to convert the Class components to Function components and use the hooks directly. For the sake of addressing your issue with legacy code though you'll have to type the "route props" manually yourself.

Example:

```js
import {
  Location,
  NavigateFunction,
  Params,
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

export interface RouterProps {
  location: Location;
  navigate: NavigateFunction;
  params: Params;
}

export interface WithRouter {
  router: RouterProps;
}

function withRouter(Component: any) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props: any) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const params = useParams();
    return <Component {...props} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />;
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter;
```

```
interface IState {
  prop1: .....
}
interface IProps extends WithRouter {
  .....
}

class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prop1: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.router.location.pathname === "/test") {
      // ...
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
      </Routes>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

***Note:** React Class components have been effectively deprecated since [February 2019](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html) when React hooks were released. It's now 2024, you should really try to write modern React using Function components. This is especially true when working with newer versions of libraries like `react-router-dom` that exclusively use React hooks.*

Comment: How do I get access to the state incase something is passed from a component?

Comment: @lrr59 What state are you asking about, `location.state`, or in your case with the above code, `this.props.router.loction.state`?

Comment: In case i pass some data to this component as state, how do i access it here?

Comment: @lrr59 You would access it via `this.props.router.location.state`.

Comment: it gives me , Property 'state' does not exist on type 'Location'.ts(2339)

Comment: @lrr59 Hmm, I'm certain that's the type, but I'll check source code when I'm back on a computer.

Comment: @lrr59 Ok yeah, the [`Location`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/a04ae6b90127ae583be08432c52b951e53f6a3c7/packages/router/history.ts#L55-L72) type definitely still has a `state` property ([docs](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#location)). What version of `react-router-dom` do you have installed? And if you have `history` installed also as a dependency for some reason, what version is that? Can you edit your post to include your package.json file so we can see if you have anything else that may cause a conflict?

Comment: got it . My bad. I was using type definitions of some other library, thanks again